# Derive an expression for the distance d (between the surface of the circle and the point P) as a function of the angle φ

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles

The problem consists of a circle with center O, and a point P. The angle φ is defined as ∠HPI, and the distance d is defined between points P and I with and angle of φ. I'm trying to derive an expression for the distance d, when variying the angle φ in the interval [-10°:10°].

If you have an idea on how to solve this, i'm all ears.

Looking forward to your answers! Thank you in advance!

I have linked to an illustration of the problem as I cannot post images yet.
[Visualization of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANPb1.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to assume that the radius $R$ of the circle is known.
Shift the coordinate system such that the center of the circle is at $(x,y)=(0,0)$ for simplicity
[i.e., subtract the coordinates of O from P...]
Let P be at $(x_p,y_p)$ in that normalized Cartesian coordinate system and assume furthermore that $R=|x_p|$
as the figure suggests (otherwise rotate the coordinate system by calculating H first). Then H is at $(x_p,0)$.
In the figure $x_p>0$ and $y_p<0$.
I is at  $(x_p-d\sin\varphi,y_p+d\cos\varphi)$ if we assume that in the figure $\varphi>0$. Because I is on the circle,
the sum of the squares must be $R^2$ as Pythagoras argued,
$$
(x_p-d\sin\varphi)^2+(y_p+d\cos\varphi)^2=R^2
$$
This is a simple quadratic equation for $d$
which can be solved by elementary methods:
$$
d^2+2d(y_p\cos\varphi-x_p\sin\varphi)+x_p^2+y_p^2-R^2=0 .
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Exactly what i was looking for.